# _tkinter.TclError: bad window path name ".!toplevel" Make the close button to exit the windows without error

Tags: python, tkinter

This error is popping up when I close a subwindows in tkinter. The program runs OK but everytime I click the close button I got that error.

I guess the right question is how can I assigned the close button to the exit command.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want is this:

```py
from tkinter import *
window = Tk()
def close():
    window.destroy()

button1 = Button(window, text = "close", command = close).pack()
window.mainloop()
```

When you click the button in the window, the window closes. The `.destroy()` command makes a widget dissapear, and it also deletes all data associated with it.

This means if you call it again, you will get an error.

Read up more about `.destroy()` [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/destroy-method-in-tkinter-python/).

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: `button1` will be set to `None` in your code, making the assignment pointless.

Comment: Your application will be terminated if `close` button is clicked, so there is no way to call the `close()` function again.

Comment: @acw1668 What do you mean?

Comment: @acw1668 Do you understand what the OP's question is?